# Shadcn select default value

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, shadcnui

I use react with shadcn there is a code:

```
<div className={'mb-8'}>
      <Select>
        <SelectTrigger className="w-[300px] text-foreground">
          <SelectValue/>
        </SelectTrigger>
        <SelectContent>
          <SelectGroup>
            <SelectItem value="apples">Apples</SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="bananas">Bananas</SelectItem>
            <SelectItem value="mangos">Mangos</SelectItem>
          </SelectGroup>
        </SelectContent>
      </Select>
    </div>
```

How to make a `default value` to be selected when the component is rendered?  For example I want `apples` to be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadcn's Select component is built with [Radix's Select Primitive](https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/select). There is usually a link at the top of Shadcn's component docs that links to the props for the component. To set a default value on `<Select>`, add the `defaultValue` prop like this:

```
<Select defaultValue='apples'>
  ...
</Select>
```

You can find more details on the props [here](https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/select#api-reference).